# Recording user pageviews, then turning this into useful data?

Tags: php, mysql

My site logs clicks to a database whenever a user views an article. This table is automatically cleared out every 3 days. We use the data to work out the most viewed pages over that 3 day period.

I'd also like to use this data for marketing purposes, eg, to determine which users like which sections of the site.

I've written a script in php that does the following:

- grab the user IDs of any logged-in member who viewed an article in the past 3 days
- for each user, i query to count how many times they viewed articles within each section, Eg, Bobby viewed 10 pages in Food & Drink, and 6 pages in Sport. I tried combining this step and the previous one together but got weird results for the totals.
- This gives me a nice array in this form:

  [Bobby Jones] => Array
      (
          [Film] => 10
          [Home Page] => 1
          [Food & Drink] => 2
          [Health & Beauty] => 1
          [Gifts & Gadgets] => 3
      )

What I want from this data is to eventually have a table that logs the data in the array above, and then when I run my queries, increments it.

Unfortunately, this adds a lot of overhead. When I have my arrays like the one above, I have to run another query to check if that combination of user and category already exists in the database, and if it does, I have to increment it by that day's values. Eg, if Bobby viewed 10 Film pages last week, and this week viewed 6, I need to UPDATE the table. If he's never viewed a Food page before, I need to INSERT instead.

This query is returning 400 or so users who've interacted with the site in the last 3 days. This means that for each I user I have to do 1 query to get their browsing totals, 1 query to see if they've already browsed that category before, and another query to update/insert, depending on whether they've browsed it or not. You can see how inefficient this is.

Can anyone suggest a better way of doing this? My ultimate goal is to end up with a table that shows me how frequently my users browse my categories, so I can say "show me all the users who like Food & Drink" etc.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: In Artificial intelligence, there's a algorithm called `Decision tree`. Even though it's got nothing to do with PHP, it can be useful (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish the UPDATE/INSERT behavior using MySQL's [`INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

You can combine the SELECT and INSERT queries using MySQL's [`INSERT...SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html).

If you post more details (say, a schema, for example), I could show you a sample query combining those two techniques, though the MySQL Manual is pretty in-depth on both subjects.

Comment: Thanks, this was what I needed. I added a UNIQUE index to some of my fields then used the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE function - this makes the page manageable (runs in about 20 seconds) and does what I need with the data, without any weird results. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MySQL and the version is sufficiently high, look into [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).  That should cut down on a query.

Then make sure your tables are properly keyed, and those two queries should be a breeze.